# Mouse click sound on fedora

Tags: linux, xorg, audio, mouse, touch-screen

I have a USB touch screen system with Fedora 14 installed. I couldn't get to play sound on any mouse click (on touch). Is there anyway to play a click sound, either by changing some configuration or using an application?

Answer (score 0):

Not too fancy solution, but it is working for me at least.

```
#!/bin/sh
PULSE_SINK=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
oldsec=$SECONDS
xinput test-xi2 --root "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" \
| grep --line-buffered "EVENT type 15 (RawButtonPress)"| while read line; do
    if [ $oldsec -lt $((SECONDS)) ];
    then paplay --volume 22000 -d $PULSE_SINK $HOME/scripts/data/click.aiff
    fi
    oldsec=$SECONDS
done
```